# DB2 DBCLOB data INSERT with Unicode data

Tags: unicode, db2

The problem at hand is to insert data into a DB2 table which has a DBCLOB column. The table's encoding is Unicode. The subsystem is a MIXED YES with Japanese CCSID set of (290, 930, 300). The application is bound ENCODING CCSID.

I was successful in FETCHING the DBCLOB's data in Unicode, no problem there. But when I turn around and try to INSERT it back, the data inserted is being interpreted as not being Unicode, seems DB2 thinks its EBCDIC DBCS/GRAPHIC, and the inserted row shows Unicode 0xFEFE. When I manually update the data being inserted to valid DBCS then the data inserts OK and shows the expected Unicode DBCS values.

To insert the data I am using a dynamically prepared INSERT statement with a placeholder for the DBCLOB column. The SQLVAR entry associated with the placeholder is a DBCLOB_LOCATOR with the CCSID set to 1200.
A DBCLOB locator is being created doing a SET dbclobloc = SUBSTR(dbclob, 1, length). The created locator is being put into SQLDA. Then the prepared INSERT is being executed.

It seems DB2 is ignoring the 1200 CCSID associated with the DBCLOB_LOCATOR SQLVAR. Attempts to put a CAST(? AS DBCLOB CCSID UNICODE) on the placeholder in the INSERT do not help because at that time DB2 seems to have made up its mind about the encoding of the data to be inserted.

I am stuck :( Any ideas?

Greg

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out and it is not good: the SET statement for the DBCLOB_LOCATOR is static SQL and the DBRM is bound ENCODING EBCDIC. Hence DB2 has no choice but to assume the data is in the CCSID of the plan.
I also tried what the books suggest and used a SELECT ... FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMYU to set the DBCLOB_LOCATOR. This should have told DB2 that the data was coming in Unicode. But it failed again, with symptoms indicating it still assumed the DBCS EBCDIC CCSID.

Not good.